# Instagram subscription - Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am having problems when trying to make a subscription to Instagram. I have created a functional servlet which handles the POST and GET as indicated at the Instagram [instructions](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/).

When trying it:

```
curl -F 'client_id=XXXXXX' -F 'client_secret=YYYYYY' -F 'object=location' -F 'aspect=media' -F 'object_id=18945195' -F 'verify_token=12345' -F 'callback_url=http://54.77.253.34/instagram/InstagramServlet'      https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions
```

it returns

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APISubscriptionError","code":400,"error_message":"Unable to reach callback URL \"http:\/\/54.77.253.34\/instagram\/InstagramServlet\"."}}
```

However, the [servlet](http://54.77.253.34/instagram/InstagramServlet) seems to be accessible through the browser and when I try

```
http://54.77.253.34/instagram/InstagramServlet?hub.challenge=somethinghere
```

it seems to be returning the `hub.challenge` it correctly.

Any ideas as to why? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the answer is then to this. I checked the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701969/instagram-ruby-gem-unable-to-reach-callback-url) you provided and I don't see any straight answer

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found the answer to this, I found an alternative way to achieve a subscription, through the [Instagram API console](https://instagram.com/developer/api-console/?hl=en).

You need to put

- In the Query the *verify_token*, *client_id*, *client_secret*
- In the Body, inside the Text something like this (or the equivalent for your subscription): `aspect=media;callback_url=http://54.77.253.34/instagram/InstagramServlet;object=location;object_id=18945195;`

I got the `hub.challenge=****` in my tomcat logs and therefore confirmed that the subscription was made.

Still, no idea as to why it is not working through the `curl`.

Comment: Is this still working for you? I am having the same problems when subscribing to tags, so I tried using the instagram API console like you.. but I am getting the same error "Unable to reach callback URL ...".

Comment: Instagram console works about one out of three times for me. But I finally manage to register my subscription. But do make sure that your callback url is accessible and implements PUT and GET and that the GET returns the correct anwser as instructed at the Instagram API page.

Comment: I also had some problems when trying to use a callback url which referred to a host that redirected to my local servlet. This redirection was not liked by Instagram and somehow I would never even receive the first confirmation GET.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with PUT. My servlet only supports GET and POST - I'll have a closer look into it. Also I noticed, that apparently during testing I made myself look suspicious and Instagram blocked the IP of my server (which has a static IP). After acquiring a new IP, at least the subscriptions started working again.

Comment: Sorry, I meant POST and GET, not PUT.